# Add DLL controller to ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: c#, web, asp.net-web-api2

Can I add a compiled DLL to my MVC project? I tried just adding it without doing any additional route configuration but was not able to access it after running the project. I am trying to add a compiled controller for my Web API 2 project.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can add a compiled DLL to your Web Api 2 project. If the configuration route bind your DLL controller actions, you will be able to navigate to them.

Just to test, you can create two "Empty Web Api 2" projects and create Test Controllers on both. Then add the DLL reference from one project to the other and check that you can access to the controllers in the referenced project from the main one.